# How do I bind to two different dependency properties in a ComboBox at the same time?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox, dependency-properties

I have a ComboBox that has I've created a binding to a List of items, but when I try to bind the selected item property, it doesn't do anything. It used to work when I bound only the SelectedValueProperty. The class already implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
 public void ComboBoxBinding() {
      Dictionary<long, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<long, string>
      Control control = new ComboBox();
      comboBoxControl = (ComboBox)control;
      comboBoxControl.SetBinding(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, createFieldBinding("myDictionary"));
      comboBoxControl.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
      comboBoxControl.SelectedValuePath = "Key";
      binding = createFieldBinding(fieldProperty);
      control.SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedItemProperty, createFieldBinding("fieldProperty")); // <-- This doesn't seem to bind.
 }

 private Binding createFieldBinding(string propertyName) {
      Binding binding = new Binding(fieldName);
      binding.Source = this.DataContext;
      binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = System.Windows.Data.UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;

 return binding;
 }
```

I set up a function that would change the dictionary variable, and the values in the ComboBox change, but I cannot get the SelectedValueProperty to change. How do I do that?

Edit: If I create a dictionary and set ItemsSource manually, it works, but when I set the binding, it doesn't.

```
 Dictionary<long, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<long, string>();
 myDictionary.Add(1, "test1");
 myDictionary.Add(2, "test2");
 myDictionary.Add(3, "test3");
 myDictionary.Add(4, "test4");
 myDictionary.Add(5, "test5");
 myDictionary.Add(6, "test6");
 myDictionary.Add(7, "test7");
 myDictionary.Add(8, "test8");
 myDictionary.Add(9, "test9");
 myDictionary.Add(10, "test10");
 comboBoxControl.ItemsSource = myDictionary; //<-- This works, but if I use Binding instead of manually setting the ItemsSource, it does not work
```

Comment: You can try something like this and see it if works 
Set the DrowdownStyle to Dropdown and bind to the ComboBox's Text property instead of SelectedItem.

Comment: The name of your `createFieldBinding` method bothers me.  You can only bind to properties, not fields.  Is `myField` a field or a property?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't doing this declaratively in XAML?

Comment: @LukeWoodward Sorry for the wording, its a property. I'll change it so it isn't as confusing.

Comment: @Charleh I'm not declaring it in XAML because the fields are created dynamically. And all bind to different things depending on the type of form the user selects. i.e. Form A = 1 ComboBox bound to list of animals and textbox bound to selected animal, Form B = 2 ComboBoxes bound to Car make, car model (respectively) and textbox for car name, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it wasn't binding was because I was defining the Dictionary in the ViewModel directly instead of creating a temporary Dictionary and setting it to the Property that implements INotifyPropertyChanged, which stops the Binding from recognizing the link between the member and the property a field was bound to.

Instead of doing:

```
 private Dictionary<long, string> _myList = new Dictionary<long, string>();
 public Dictionary<long, string> MyList {
      get { return _myList; }
      set { _myList = value;
            PropertyChanged("MyList"); }
 }

 public void Init() {
      _myList.Add(1, "One");
 }
```

I had to set a temporary Dictionary and apply that to the Property.

```
 private Dictionary<long, string> _myList = new Dictionary<long, string>();
 public Dictionary<long, string> MyList {
      get { return _myList; }
      set { _myList = value;
            PropertyChanged("MyList"); }
 }

 public void Init() {
      Dictionary<long, string> tempList = new Dictionary<long, string>();
      tempList.Add(1, "One");
      MyList = tempList;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public long SelectedValue { get { return selectedValue; } set { selectedValue = value; Notify("SelectedValue"); } }
    private long selectedValue;
    private Dictionary<long, string> myDictionary;
    public Dictionary<long, string> MyDictionary { get { return myDictionary; } set { myDictionary = value; Notify("MyDictionary"); } }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        ComboBoxBinding();
        MyDictionary = new Dictionary<long, string>() { { 1, "abc" }, { 2, "xyz" }, { 3, "pqr" } };
        SelectedValue = 2;

    }
    public void ComboBoxBinding()
    {
        Control control = new ComboBox();
        comboBoxControl = (ComboBox)control;
        comboBoxControl.SetBinding(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, createFieldBinding("MyDictionary"));
        comboBoxControl.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
        comboBoxControl.SelectedValuePath = "Key";
       comboBoxControl.SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty, createFieldBinding("SelectedValue"));
    }

    private Binding createFieldBinding(string fieldName)
    {
        Binding binding = new Binding(fieldName);
        binding.Source = this.DataContext;
        binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = System.Windows.Data.UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        return binding;
    }
    private void Notify(string propName)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged!=null)
            PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion
}
```

You can bind Properties only.Fields can not be Binded.I hope this will help.